# Force Navbar elements to stay in one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wan't the elements of my **Bootstrap Navbar** to **stay in one line** at every width.

I know this question has already been asked [several times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=navbar+in+one+line) and I've tried various solutions, but no one worked for my case.

Here's my code:

```css
#head-navbar {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-collapse" id="head-navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="#" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="#">DE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">IT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I want my Navbar to look like this on a smaller screen:

[image]
and not like this:

[image]

Comment: You want both ul to display inline ? because with your edited question it's fine now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-block;` to your `li` and they will be displayed inline.

```
.nav>li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also if you want to display both `ul` in the same line you can do the same thing to the `ul` elements.Here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpjoe0Lt/7/) for both `ul` inline.

Also in firefox you will have a breakpoint in 768px so you should remove the `white-space:nowrap`

```
#head-navbar {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

P.s : i don't know if it is a TYPO but you should use `.pull-right` instead of `.navbar-right` to float right an element

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is not giving me the result I wanted. I just edited my question to clarify my problem. Thanks, just changed it to `.pull-right`.

Comment: I just edited my js fiddle and it is working perfectly. I just tested it and it works great even in 290px width but like we know the min width of mobile phones is 320px

Comment: I just tested both fiddles and I'm still not getting the result, as explained in my question. Maybe you forgot to save it?

Comment: Just to clarify something you cannot infinitely shrink down the window because it's normally that there is no place for 5 words to stay in a line which has a width of 100px. So in my jsfiddle that i posted i can shrink down to 290px and there is the breakpoint where that problem happends but your target device is not 290 px it's 320px so in 320px it works great.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle for extremely and non-existing screen sizes https://jsfiddle.net/dpjoe0Lt/6/

Comment: Sure. I just don't want it to break at a width of 768px. Just figured out that your fiddle is working perfectly in IE & Chrome, but the breakpoint on Firefox is at 768px.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of **media queries**, so on smaller screens it changes the style. Just add these:

```
 .navbar-nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: right;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is not giving me the right result. I just edited my question to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.pull-right{
  float:right;
  }
#head-navbar {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  width:initial;
  float:left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav { 
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px)
{
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-collapse" id="head-navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="#" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="#">DE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">IT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is not giving me the right result. I just edited my question to clarify my problem.

Comment: ok..now i'm edited my code,check it and if you need more modification tell me,i will help you

Answer (score 0):

Add the below css, This should work for you.

```css
#head-navbar {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  width:initial;
  float:left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav { 
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px)
{
  .nav.navbar-nav.pull-right { float:none !important; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-collapse" id="head-navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="#" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="#">DE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">IT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is not giving me the right result. I just edited my question to clarify my problem.

Comment: Now the `pull-right` Navbar slides to the left at the breakpoint width of 768px.