# Navigation bar breaks into a new line instead of resizing

Tags: html, css, navigationbar, responsive, autoresize

So basically I have made a bunch of conflicting `div`s, but they all managed to work except for my navigation bar. I've tried sitting the different containers inside my `top` container to automatically fit to the screen by using percentage instead of pixels. But whenever I open up my site on smaller screens the icons in the bar ends up jumping down to the next line?

How do I achieve resizing the buttons and the image automatically so they can all fit into one line, by using **pure CSS**? Also the main `div` for the navigation bar is supposed to be above the background split.
If you take a look at my CSS I've also tried setting

```
.navbar>li {
    display: inline-block;
```

This turned out to have no effect at all

CSS:

```
.top {
    background-color: ;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.navbar {
    background-color: #FDF3E7;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    border: 10px double #C63D0F;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right 10%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
}

.navbar>li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.hot-container {
    min-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width:80%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

a.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 78%
}
```

Heres the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z400tzkb/

Comment: The image is supposed to be a logo on the same line as the buttons, as shown in the fiddle it is actually centered in between the line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force Navbar elements to stay in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266989/force-navbar-elements-to-stay-in-one-line)

Comment: I had already tried with setting the .navbar>li to function as an inline-block, this was without effect, which was the given response to the question you linked