# Issues with Bootstrap 4 fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap navbar that I want it to be fixed at the top, so when the content below is scrolled, the navbar remains at the same place. So far this requirement works fine, but there are two issues:

The first issue is that when I select an item from the any of the two dropdown lists, their lengths change. I want the lengths to be fixed.

The second issue is that I do not need the "Report Type", "Code" and "Submit" controls to be collapsible. This page will be used solely on a web browser on a desktop or laptop. I just need these three controls to be fixed on the right. This means that the navbar length will be fixed, and if the browser is resized smaller, the user would have to scroll to the right to see the rest of the navbar. How to remove the collapsible feature?

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="btn-group dropright">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false">Reports</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Reports</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Settings</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Logout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul> <!-- If I remove this, the controls to the right will shift to the left -->
            <form id="report-form" class="form-inline" action="/test" method="POST">
                <label class="mr-1" for="report_type_button" style="color: white !important;">Report Type:</label>
                <select
                    class="custom-select mr-sm-3" id="report-type-button">
                    <option value="IMRS" selected>XXX Report</option>
                    <option value="IMRF">YYY Report</option>
                </select> <label class="mr-1" for="report_type_button" style="color: white !important;">Code:</label>
                <div class="dropdown mr-sm-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">AAAAA</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">AAAAA</button>
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">BBBBB BBBBB</button>
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
                <input id="unit-code" name="unitCode" type="hidden" value="" /> <input id="report-date" name="reportDate"
                    type="hidden" value="" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 70px;">
        <table class="table table-hover small">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="border-0">Report ID: ABCDEFG</th>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="border-0" style="text-align: center">XXX Report</th>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="border-0" style="text-align: right">Page: 1 / 1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="3" class="border-0">Report Date: 16/04/2020</th>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="9" class="border-0" style="text-align: right">Updated Time: 16/04/2020 11:30:58</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">I/O</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Sender</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Receiver</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Type</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Reference</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Currency</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Amount</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Value Date</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Acceptance Time</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Last Updated Time</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-warning">
                    <td nowrap>I</td>
                    <td nowrap>XXXXXXXXXXX</td>
                    <td nowrap>YYYYYYYYYYY</td>
                    <td nowrap>XXXX</td>
                    <td nowrap>ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</td>
                    <td nowrap>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                    <td nowrap>USD</td>
                    <td nowrap>1000.00</td>
                    <td nowrap>16/04/2020</td>
                    <td nowrap>16/04/2020 11:30:58</td>
                    <td nowrap>16/04/2020 11:30:58</td>
                    <td nowrap>DUP</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('.dropdown-item').on('click', function() {
            var btnObj = $(this).parent().siblings('button');
            $(btnObj).text($(this).text());
            $(btnObj).val($(this).text());
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDITED**:

I want the controls to stay in one row, but if I resize the browser to make the width smaller, the controls will overflow to the next row.

[image]

Comment: please clarfiy your question in brief.

Comment: (1) How to make the dropdown lists have fixed lengths regardless of what item is chosen?, (2) How to make the navbar fixed and non-collapsible, and all controls on it stay on one row even if the browser is resized?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

For `fixed-dropdown`, I added `fixed_dropdown` class in `dropdown-btn`.

For `fixed navbar` and `non-collapsable`, you can use `fixed-top` and `navbar-expand` class.

what you mean by in one row?

```css
.fixed_dropdown {
    width: 10rem;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="btn-group dropright">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false">Reports</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Reports</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Settings</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Logout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul> <!-- If I remove this, the controls to the right will shift to the left -->
            <form id="report-form" class="form-inline" action="/test" method="POST">
                <label class="mr-1" for="report_type_button" style="color: white !important;">Report Type:</label>
                <select
                    class="custom-select mr-sm-3" id="report-type-button">
                    <option value="IMRS" selected>XXX Report</option>
                    <option value="IMRF">YYY Report</option>
                </select> <label class="mr-1" for="report_type_button" style="color: white !important;">Code:</label>
                <div class="dropdown mr-sm-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle fixed_dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">AAAAA</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">AAAAA</button>
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">BBBBB BBBBB</button>
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">CCCCC CCCCC CCCCC</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
                <input id="unit-code" name="unitCode" type="hidden" value="" /> <input id="report-date" name="reportDate"
                    type="hidden" value="" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 70px;">
        <table class="table table-hover small">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="border-0">Report ID: ABCDEFG</th>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="border-0" style="text-align: center">XXX Report</th>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="border-0" style="text-align: right">Page: 1 / 1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="3" class="border-0">Report Date: 16/04/2020</th>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="9" class="border-0" style="text-align: right">Updated Time: 16/04/2020 11:30:58</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">I/O</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Sender</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Receiver</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Type</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Reference</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Currency</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Amount</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Value Date</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Acceptance Time</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Last Updated Time</th>
                    <th class="align-top" scope="col">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-warning">
                    <td nowrap>I</td>
                    <td nowrap>XXXXXXXXXXX</td>
                    <td nowrap>YYYYYYYYYYY</td>
                    <td nowrap>XXXX</td>
                    <td nowrap>ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</td>
                    <td nowrap>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                    <td nowrap>USD</td>
                    <td nowrap>1000.00</td>
                    <td nowrap>16/04/2020</td>
                    <td nowrap>16/04/2020 11:30:58</td>
                    <td nowrap>16/04/2020 11:30:58</td>
                    <td nowrap>DUP</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('.dropdown-item').on('click', function() {
            var btnObj = $(this).parent().siblings('button');
            $(btnObj).text($(this).text());
            $(btnObj).val($(this).text());
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, now the dropdown lists have fixed widths after using your solution. Please see my edits above regarding the controls not staying in one row.

Comment: If you want to like your edit, in resize your controls overlaying each other. so for that you need scrollbar and its look weird

Comment: please explain to me, how you want your dropdowns on a small screen with the help of one image

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `.navbar-expand-lg` class from your nav tag since you don't want to collapse your navigation bar on any breakpoint.
Also you don't need to add `.navbar-toggler` button. This will create a hamburger button to toggle your collapsed items, in your case items inside `#navbarSupportedContent`. So remove the following:

```
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
```

Also remove `.collapse` and `.navbar-collapse` classes from this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Now when I resize the browser to make the length shorter, the three controls flow to the next line. Is it possible for the navbar to be a fixed one line?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266989/force-navbar-elements-to-stay-in-one-line/39267058

Comment: That solution works for Bootstrap 3, but doesn't work for Bootstrap 4. Anyway, do you have a solution to fix the two dropdown lists? Their lengths change when a different item is selected.

Comment: You can set ```max-width``` on the dropdown button for its maximum width. Also set ```overflow: hidden``` so that its content doesn't overflow and instead the overflowing content will be hidden.